# Looking for recommendations on reseller web hosting

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, web-hosting

The company I work for is currently doing its own web hosting in a co-location paying 300 a month with 3 servers hosting about a 100 sites.  After some quick analysis we have decided to go the way of reseller web hosting.

I am now looking around at companies that allow you to resell web hosting and have come across two so far that seemed decent.

innohosting.com and hostdime.com

Does anyone have any feedback on either or have any recommendations? The features I'm looking for is it needing a control panel (like cpanel) and some sort of way to manage accounts.  Any input would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mosso allows for reselling as well as mediatemple. We currently use both services.

Comment: i was actually just looking at mosso.  it seems like mediatemple is much cheaper.  they are both cloud computer as far as i can tell, which is probably much better then shared?

Comment: Actually Mosso is pretty cheap. $100 per month for as many sites as you want to host.

Answer (score 0):

Crystaltech does reselling, also. I haven't done that, but I've used them for a long time and have been very happy.